# Countable and uncountable Cartesian product

Tags: notation

We can  recursively define a tuple:
\begin{align*}
\langle x  \rangle &= x\\
\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1} \rangle &= \langle \langle x_1,\ldots,x_{n}\rangle, x_{n+1}\rangle   \\
\end{align*}
We can define functions as sets of tuples $\langle x,y \rangle$ (with a unique $y$ for each $x$).
So, the Cartesian product of an indexed family $ \{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ can be defined as:
$$
\prod_{i \in I} X_i =
\left\{\left. f: I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\ \right|\ (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\right\}$$
Another way is to define:   ${\huge \times}_{i =1}^{n}  X_i$:
\begin{align*}
{\huge \times}_{i =1}^1  X_i &\text{ stands for } X_1 \\
{\huge \times}_{i =1}^{n+1}  X_i &\text{ stands for } 
          \left({\huge \times}_{i =1}^n  X_i  \right)\times X_{n+1}\\
X_1 \times X_2 &\text{ stands for } \{ \langle a,b \rangle : a \in X_1  \wedge  b \in X_2\}\\
%X_1 \times \ldots\times   X_n &\text{ stands for } {\huge \times}_{i =1}^{n}  X_i
\end{align*}

For $I=\{1, \dots, n\}$ there is a one-to-one correspondence from 
$\prod_{i \in \{1, \dots, n\}} X_i$
to
 ${\huge \times}_{i =1}^{n}  X_i$. 
For example, if
$
A_1={1}, A_2={2}, A_3={3}  
$:
\begin{align*}
  \prod_{i \in \{1, 2\}} X_i &=
                 \big\{ \{ \langle 1,1 \rangle, \langle 2,2 \rangle, \langle 3,3 \rangle\} \big\}\\
  {\huge \times}_{i =1}^{n}  X_i &= \big\{\langle \langle 1,2 \rangle, 3 \rangle \big\}
                                 =\big\{\langle 1,2, 3 \rangle \big\}
\end{align*}

If $I$ is uncountable,   the equivalent operation ${\huge \times}$ can't be implemented. I am not sure about  $I$ countably infinite.

Now, my curiosity concerns whether there is a proper name to label/distinguish the operation ${\huge \times}$ from  $\prod$ and possibly a standard
notation.

Comment: *If* $I$ *is uncountable, the equivalent operation* ${\huge \times}$ *can't be implemented.* --- Surely something reasonable along these lines can be done using transfinite induction, but I don't have time to look into this now.